# jquery onchange losing selected state

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have put a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/JjBPd/

```
$(function () {
    var options = $("select#areafilter").children("option");
    var selectoption = $("select#regionfilter");
    $(selectoption).on("change", function () {
        var selected = $(this).children("option:selected").data("path");
        $(options).appendTo("select#areafilter");
        $(options).each(function () {
            var region = $(this).data("region");
            if (region != selected && region != 'default') {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
        if (selected == 'default') {
            $(options).appendTo("select#areafilter");
        }
    });
});
```

Basically if you select a region, then select and area, and then select filter by region again, it loads with the last option of the select list highlighted, I have tried using selected='selected' and focus but with no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the area select box reset each time the region is changed, you can use jQuery's `prop()` method:

```
$(selectoption).on("change", function () {
  // reset the selected area
  options.prop('selected',false);

  ...
```

See a [forked and updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mike_marcacci/qSjgq/).

***EDIT:***
Here's the code updated to work in Firefox as well. Turns out Firefox creates new elements when appended, whereas Webkit just references the existing ones. Thus you have to reset the newly appended options. The Fiddle should be updated.

```
$(function () {
    var options = $("select#areafilter").children("option");
    var selectoption = $("select#regionfilter");
    $(selectoption).on("change", function () {

        var selected = $(this).children("option:selected").data("path");
        $(options).appendTo("select#areafilter");
        $(options).each(function () {
            var region = $(this).data("region");
            if (region != selected && region != 'default'){
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
        if (selected == 'default') {
            $(options).appendTo("select#areafilter");
        }

        // reset the selected area
        $("select#areafilter").children().prop('selected',false).first().prop('selected',true);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to reply, sadly still doesnt work in firefox :(